# Need advise on structuring multiple angular apps under one 'apps' folder

Tags: angularjs, architecture

We are in process of structuring our code folder project, which will contain multiple independent angular apps ( they may share common services, which can be injected into the apps )

We should be able to build and deploy each app separately ( have a independent gulpfile for each app)

I am not really sure how to share common services, i guess we would need a top level app which will contain one of the app when deployed.

How and where can i configure which app to be built or served when top level app is accessed.
I have looked at manually bootstrapping the angular app, but not sure where that code would go ?

Should each app have its own bower_components folder, or can they share from the top level app itself.

Any direction, links to blog  will help.

Here is what i have come up so far:

```
apps/
  common/
  appOne/
    components/
    services/
    appOne.js
    index.html
  appTwo/
  ...
  ...
  bower_components/
  index.html
  package.json
```

Comment: can you treat and test those common services individually? For instance, a directive or service can have a repository of their own, which you can then just include as a bower component in every application you're writing. In that case the location of your files is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Jorg, yes we can. so we basically include the reference in the individual index.html. And how about manually bootstrapping the independent apps.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure about what you meant. Angular is meant to be a one page application, there is no proper way of switching between apps - it's simply against angulars architecture. I'd make either one large app or several independent ones. Shared components are included with bower, so no overlap.